# Using mikva under owners conditions

Tags: halacha, mikvah-ritual-bath, gezel-stealing, tevilas-keilim-dipping

I recently passed a keilim mikva which is located in a highly congested area.There is no charge to use the mikvah. Right above the mikva there was a big sign that said " you do not have permission to use this mikvah if you double park".

My question is if one did double park and  used the mikvah anyways is it a good tevila,since it might be considered stealing,and in a case someone who didn't see the sign until after they already used it do they have to reimburse the owner of the mikvah since it was used without permission?

Comment: +1 cute. Although mitzvah habaah b'aveira seemingly would not apply so the dipping would help . I'd wonder more about the bracha al tevilas keilim. Maybe stick that in? Also the mikva is not omed lischor so there would be no price to pay bidieved.

Comment: Why do you think stealing would affect the efficacy of tevila?

Comment: Kofin al midas Sedom? Does the owner of the mikvah actually lose anything if you use the mikvah without permission?

Comment: @mevaqesh - Stealing often changes the halachic status of otherwise completely kosher things. In the light of this season, a stolen esrog or sukkah, even if they are kosher, immediately become not-kosher for the thief.

Comment: @ezra editing in what one knows about that would greatly improve the question. As of now, it shows no research.

Comment: @user6591 Does the rule of "mitzvah habaah b'aveira " apply to this situation? Double parking doesn't seem to be related to the mikvah process. E.g. it's not the same as breaking the lock to the mikvah in order to use it. It would be different if the sign said "You can't use the mikvah if you block the driveway entrance>" since that relates directly to the mikvah property.

Comment: @DanF I wrote that I don't think it applies. I don't think your case applies either. It is still somewhat removed from the actual item.

Comment: Please more clearly define "double parking" in terms of where? On the street away from the mikvah or directly in the mikvah area so that it blocks other cars from getting into the mikvah driveway / parking lot, etc.

Comment: @DanF It seems to me that the double-parking is relevant.  Often houses of worship fight with the government and the neighbors concerning the issue of traffic tie-ups.  A person double-parking (i.e. blocking cars from pulling out of their parking spot), or blocking driveways, causes consternation and anger among the neighbors, giving justification to their anti-frumkite feelings.  Next time you need a permit to build a mikvah or add to a shul, then watch who petitions against your permit.

Answer (score 1):

Tevilis keilim the mitzvah is the result not the action- cf tosfos end of nidah- Reb elchanos says in k"h that the concept of mitzvah Habah baveira doesn't apply to a mitzvah which is the result so would be kosher .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Consider clarifying where rabbi elhanan says this.

Comment: First, welcome to Mi Yodea.  Because readers may or may not  have yeshiva backgrounds -- you might want to expand your answers by explaining the practical application and meaning.  Less Yeshivish, more English.

Comment: My apologies- thank you- there are different type of commandments in the Torah- some commandments the Torah wants a specific action e.g shake the myrtle, keep Saturday etc, other commandments the Torah wants a specific result for example tevila..- Mitzvos in the second category tosfos in nida 57 says that there is not a better and worse way to do then because the Torah only cares about the result not the action- reb elchanon in kovetz haoros says that in the second catagory as well there would be no din of mh"b because the result was done ....

Comment: @user16291 welcome to MY. Comments that clarify a comment should go in the answer as [edits](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/87464/edit) - this way the reader of the answer has everything in one place. Hope to see you around in the future, there is a lot you can bring this site. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site.