# Tevila in Keilim Mikva without permission

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing, tevilas-keilim-dipping

Recently was at a Keilim Mikva which had a sign "No Tevila allowed for outside utensils. Only utensils purchased at this store may be Toiveled here". I was wondering if one goes ahead and does Tevilas Keilim in such a Mikva is the Tevila good? Yes it is wrong to do so, as the owner obviously doesn't want one to use the Mikva unless they purchased an item from him, however at the end of the day does the Tevila work in such a case? (Sources please)

Comment: *Mitzvos lav le'hanos nitnu*?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE but in this case I understand it is the store's *mikve*

Comment: Why would you think not ?

Comment: I don't see how you had proper kavana (acc to the Poskim that you need kavana) while making the bracha (assuming you did), knowing that you "think you're stealing to do a mitzvah"....

Comment: @Two no bracha is supposed to be recited when stealing in general בוצע ברך נאץ ה

Comment: @TwoOs Not sure why the bracha would be me'akev anyway.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86041/using-mikva-under-owners-conditions

Comment: @mbloch *Le'mai naphka minah*?

Answer (score 1):

*Poskim* rule that immersion doesn't need intention (see details [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tevilat_Keilim#cite_note-21)). Therefore, as the OU writes ([here](https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/can-tovel-keilim-immerse-utensils-mikvah-without-knowledge-owner/)), if utensils fell into a *mikvah*, even unintentionally, the *tevila* is valid.

Therefore an immersion as you describe is valid. This is true even though doing it against the will of the owner is forbidden because they can decide how people should use their private *mikve*.

I checked the above with R Binyamin Tabady who concurs.

Comment: I'm not clear on the issues here -- would the tevila not be good as mitzvah haba b'aveira? Can someone make a rule forbidding someone else from performing a mitzvah? (unlike lulav, there is no requirement for ownership)